# Using A SUM() In Update Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, update, cte

I thought I had this syntax nailed down, but I am getting an error of Incorrect syntax near ) when I attempt to execute.  Why is my syntax not correct?

```
    ;with CTE As
    (
         Select max(entryID) As "MaxEntryID"
         ,userID FROM loghist group by userID
    )
    Select es.userID As userID, cm.companyName, SUM(COALESCE(eq.TotalValue,0)) As TotalValue
    FROM CTE vn
    Inner Join loghist es
    ON vn.userID=es.userID
    AND Coalesce(vn."MaxEntryID",0)=COALESCE(es.entryID,0)
    INNER JOIN company cm
    ON es.customerid = cm.customerid    
    Inner Join loghistpart ep
    ON ep.loghist = es.loghistid
    Inner Join lhq eq
    On eq.loghistpartid = ep.loghistpartid
    GROUP BY es.userID, cm.companyName
)
UPDATE fvi
Set TotalValue = loghistdTotalValue
FROM FullVarianceInfo fvi
INNER JOIN CTE mvn
ON fvi.userID = mvn.userID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you nest CTEs, you need to name them.

```
;with CTE As
(
     Select max(entryID) As "MaxEntryID"
     ,userID FROM loghist group by userID
), 
CTE2 AS (
Select es.userID As userID, cm.companyName, SUM(COALESCE(eq.TotalValue,0)) As TotalValue
FROM CTE vn
Inner Join loghist es
ON vn.userID=es.userID
AND Coalesce(vn."MaxEntryID",0)=COALESCE(es.entryID,0)
INNER JOIN company cm
ON es.customerid = cm.customerid    
Inner Join loghistpart ep
ON ep.loghist = es.loghistid
Inner Join lhq eq
On eq.loghistpartid = ep.loghistpartid
GROUP BY es.userID, cm.companyName
)

    UPDATE fvi
    Set TotalValue = loghistdTotalValue
    FROM FullVarianceInfo fvi
    INNER JOIN CTE2 mvn
    ON fvi.userID = mvn.userID
```

It also looks like your `UPDATE` columns are backwards as written.

`Set TotalValue = loghistdTotalValue`

Should probably be

`Set loghistdTotalValue = TotalValue`